# request.POST.get() always returning None

Tags: django, django-views

I am completely new to django , you can I just started it today

when I am making a POST request with parameters using postman ,  I am always getting None for email,password, name and other variables

```
@csrf_exempt
def signup(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    os = request.POST.get('os')
    device_id = request.POST.get('device_id')
    version = request.POST.get('version')
    device = request.POST.get('device')
    print "email value is = %s", email
    user=AppUser.objects.get_or_create(email=password,password=password)
    user.save()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"result": True}), content_type='application/json')
```

Please help , Why it is always showing None even though I am passing values from POST request for email and for other parameters

Below is the body request from post man using POST

http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1.0/signup/?email=nagu@nagu.com&password=nagendra&name=nagendra&os=android&device_id=12345678&version=23.0.1&device=samsung

below postman screen shot

[image]

Comment: First, it is highly recommended to use `Django Forms` for getting data directly from request. Second, please share your template which is responsible for posting the data or write the output of printing request.POST

Comment: I do not want to use forms , I want to get the data through api using POST request

Comment: Would you display the content of request.POST?

Comment: @kia, If I am using GET then I am able to get the values whatever I am passing through url, I am guess I am missing some concept related to request.

Comment: I need the body of your request to say something useful for you :)

Comment: I made the below request from postman using POST method http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1.0/signup/?email=nagu@nagu.com&password=nagendra&name=nagendra&os=android&device_id=12345678&version=23.0.1&device=samsung

Comment: I have edited the question ,and added body of request please have a look

Comment: Dude, you have shared you localhost URL which is not accessible out of your machine. But I guess you are passing your data via query string which is accessible via request.GET

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#get-and-post

Comment: yeah it os on my local machine only , I have given it to get some idea . Believe me I am making POST request , If will make GET the it will through 404 as you can see the condition on top in view

Comment: Dude, I believe you!
I say you are making post request, but you are not passing data via post.
`email=nagu@nagu.com&password=nagendra&name=nagendra&os=android&device_id=12345678&version=23.0.1&device=samsung` says that you are passing data via query string which is accessible via request.GET. You need for example html form to post them by request.

Comment: I understand, please see postman in chrome app, in which I can select POST and once I add parameters it displays like GET request so that people can what request they are making, may be I wrong but please have a look at postman chrome app , thanks for your time sir

Answer (score 5):

The parameters you added to the url are `GET` parameters not `POST` parameters. `POST` parameters are in the request body and not visible through urls. Even you specify your request method is `POST` with your original url, you are not going to send any data.

If you in your commandline do something like:

```
curl --data "email=nagu@nagu.com&password=nagendra&name=nagendra&os=android&device_id=12345678&version=23.0.1&device=samsung" http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1.0/signup/
```

It should send `POST` data to your view.

Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) and answer on how `POST` requests are delivered.

Comment: `Curl` http://curl.haxx.se/ is the most basic one. But it's command line tool and not easy to use. If you want to write programs to do it, try python requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/. It's the easiest client side program I ever had.

Comment: You can certainly send POST data in Postman; there's a whole box for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried postman in chrome.
Below is the screenshot.
Does this work for you?

[image: postman in chrome]

Comment: this does not work for me, I have tried same thing  and I am getting email can not be null, I do not know whats happening, is it something related to postman? , if I am using command line it is working like charm but using postman it is not working.

Comment: I have tested postman and it works in y case. Maybe it's better if you share screenshot or something helpful for getting close to the problem.

Comment: I have added postman screen shot in question , please have a look

Comment: 1. What value is set for `Header (1)` tab?
2. Check AppUser.objects.get_or_create(email=`password`,password=password)
3. Share content of request.POST displaying in your debug page (bottom of yellow page)

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your parameter of body in postman is correct, it
should be "x-www-form-urlencoded". 
THKS!

Answer (score 0):

check your header 
you probably may have

Content-type set to application/json